# How do I check to see if Redhat (CentOS) has backported a security fix for Samba?

Tags: linux, security

http://www.samba.org/samba/security/CVE-2010-2063.html

How can I check to see if the Redhat (CentOS) repositories have backported a fix?

Comment: Related question (which I believe would answer yours):
Does CentOS / RHEL have a web-based package list and search site, like http://packages.ubuntu.com ? That is a very handy site for me.

Comment: Nope it doesn't! http://serverfault.com/questions/239205/official-online-rpm-package-browser-search-for-centos/239290#239290

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a combination of RedHat Bugzilla, RedHat Errata, and CentOS mirrors.
First, using the CVE-2010-XXXX visit https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2010-XXXX.
When you see that the issue has been addressed follow that link to the RedHat errata.
Grab the rpm version and head to a CentOS mirror.

For example the latest sudo vulnerability (CVE-2010-1646):

bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=CVE-2010-1646 (last comment->)
rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2010-0475.html (copy sudo-1.7.2p1-7.el5_5.x86_64.rpm)
mirror.cs.vt.edu/pub/CentOS/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/ (it matches RedHat's errrata)

The samba vuln hasn't been packaged for CentOS and sent upstream as far as I can tell.

Comment: Link to redhat's offical CVE database: https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/ which gives a CVE orientated view, rather than a bug orientated one.

Answer (score 6):

`rpm -q --changelog <package name>` will show the package changelog, where vulnerabilities that have been patched in a package are enumerated. Additionally, the CentOS [package announcement mailing list](http://lists.centos.org/mailman/listinfo/centos-announce) also gives the added portions of the changelog when the package is released.