# Official online RPM package browser / search for CentOS

Tags: centos, website, rhel5, search, packages

I am looking for something that resembles [packages.debian.org Debian Package Browser](http://packages.debian.org) only for **CentOS** 5 and/or **RHEL** 5 [Red Hat Enterprise Linux].

Comment: It's not a web interface, but you can search packages and get metadata information with `yum search` and `yum info`.

Comment: You may also be interested in EPEL http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: It's interesting that Fedora has a [fairly good package browser](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per my comment, I don't believe there is an equivalent to the "packages.debian.org" central package archive (with web interface) in CentOS.

It's something I think is really missing!

Comment: yum search pkg is still the best way, unfortunately.

Comment: I just wanted to find out what is the Python version in CentOS 5.8 -- it's incredibly hard to find out via google. A web-based package search engine would really be nice.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I agree. I do find distrowatch useful though http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos

Answer (score 23):

https://pkgs.org/ provides a "Linux Packages Search" for several distributions, including CentOS 5–7.

Comment: nice; fast, concise, and broad

Answer (score 5):

People are working on one for CentOS. it is called [Pandora](https://projects.centos.org/trac/pandora/). Currently, the best bet is to use a GUI based package manager running on CentOS itself in an X windows system (called [yumex](http://www.yum-extender.org/cms/node/4)).

**Update**: http://rpm.pbone.net though cumbersome, allows searching the RPMs of various redhat-based distros

Comment: The link to Pandora is now a 404.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would advise you to hit up mirrors.centos.org if you are looking for the packages.

Comment: Not the actual packages (the files) but a meta search engine like packages.debian.org

Comment: @unixman83 this is something I really miss when dealing with centos servers. The debian package archives are amazing in comparison, and I'm yet to find anything similar for centos.

Comment: @Coops, if you are saying there isn't currently one. Then if you could type that as an answer; I will consider it as the answer to my question.

Comment: @unixman83 - as requested, done! Cheers.